# Can't "Enable Editing" on my gridview

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, asp.net-3.5, linqdatasource

I'm trying to connect my gridview to a LinqDataSource to select, update, insert and delete records.  I am able to get into edit mode and cancel out of edit mode but when I click update nothing happens.

I've found a few things online that say to check the "Enable Editing" box in the gridview smart tag but when I go into the smart tag the only check boxes that appear are: Enable Paging, Enable Sorting and Enable selection.  The others don't appear.  Dose anyone see a problem with what I am doing below?

```
  <asp:GridView   ID="gv_Personnel" 
                    runat="server" 
                    OnRowDataBound="gv_Personnel_DataBind"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    ShowFooter="True" 
                    DataKeyNames="BudgetLineID"
                    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
                    DataSourceID="lds_Personnel"
                    >
        <Columns>                 
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Level of Staff" DataField="LineDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hrs/Units requested" DataField="NumberOfUnits" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hrs/Units of Applicant Cost Share" DataField="" NullDisplayText="0" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hrs/Units of Partner Cost Share" DataField="" NullDisplayText="0" />
            <asp:BoundField FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
                FooterText="TOTAL PERSONNEL SERVICES:" HeaderText="Rate" 
                DataFormatString="{0:C}" DataField="UnitPrice" >
            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount Requested" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  
                FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                <FooterStyle BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Applicant Cost Share" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
                FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                <FooterStyle BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Partner Cost Share" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
                FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                <FooterStyle BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Projet Cost" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
                FooterStyle-BorderWidth="2" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                <FooterStyle BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="lds_Personnel" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="nrm.FRGPproposal.FrgpropDataContext" 
        Select="new (BudgetLineID, UnitPrice, LineDescription, NumberOfUnits)" 
        TableName="BudgetLines" 
        Where="ProposalID == @PropNumber &amp;&amp; BudgetLineTypeCode == @BudgetLineTypeCode" 
        EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="PropNumber" SessionField="PropNumber" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="S" Name="BudgetLineTypeCode" Type="Char" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it without using anonymous types?  In code, you can't update anon. types in the database...

Comment: Select="new (BudgetLineID, UnitPrice, LineDescription, NumberOfUnits)"

Comment: Yes Select New creates the anonymous type; work with the base table if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was caused by me having the Select value set on my LinqDataSoruce.  See updated LDS below:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="lds_Personnel" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="nrm.FRGPproposal.FrgpropDataContext" 
    TableName="BudgetLines" 
    Where="ProposalID == @PropNumber &amp;&amp; BudgetLineTypeCode == @BudgetLineTypeCode" 
    EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="PropNumber" SessionField="PropNumber" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="S" Name="BudgetLineTypeCode" Type="Char" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```